# switch the positions of date and author

Tags: titles, titling

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}

\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    \vskip0.5em}%
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5mm}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Dimitrios Anagnostou}
\date{mydate}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

How can I reverse the positions of the `\date` and `\author` fields?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling,parskip}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\def\@maketitle{% modified from titling.sty
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \vspace*{\droptitle}
  \maketitlehooka
  {\@bspretitle \@title \@bsposttitle}
  \maketitlehookb
  {\@bspredate \@date \@bspostdate}
  \maketitlehookc
  {\@bspreauthor \@author \@bspostauthor}
  \maketitlehookd
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    \vskip0.5em}%
}

\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Dimitrios Anagnostou}
\date{mydate}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: reordered title]

Answer (score 1):

May be too obvious, but as `\author` and `\date` have the same format in this case, there are a quick and dirty way:

```
% for your eyes only ⚉ 
\author{\today}
\date{Dimitrios Anagnostou}
```

And yes, conceptually is a sacrilege. Nobody should know what you have done. Destroy your source code after the PDF compilation.

Comment: You can make this a little less bad, by doing some thing like `let\tmp\author \let\author\date \let\date\tmp`

Comment: @Mark Less dirty and less quick too. `:-)`

Comment: I am guilty using your trick.  I never did \author{\today}, but I have done \date{Name of the School that both authors are from}.  (Actually it was the coauthor's idea.)  Instead of destroying the source code, it is now on arxiv.  I will admit that someone once saw it (on my laptop screen, not on arxiv) and was indeed quite offended, to the point of trying to cook up alternative solution.